# Solidity Events are not emitting properly, even with the successfull transaction!

Tags: solidity, remix, nft, erc-721, events

Solidity Events are not emitting properly.

This is the code "Nftfactory.sol":

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "../MPContractFactory/Interfaces/IDeployNftMinting.sol";
import "../Interfaces/IAdminRoles.sol";
import "../Interfaces/ICommissions.sol";
import "../Interfaces/IMasterWhiteListing.sol";

error Insufficient_CollectionFee_sent();
error User_not_whitelisted();

contract NftFactory {
    address[] private s_allCollections;
    mapping(address => address[]) private s_userCollecions;
    uint256 private collectionCreationFee;
    uint256 private collectionCreationCommission;
    bool public _whitelisted;
    address private MPSuperAdmin;
    address private PSuperAdmin;
    address private ARolesContractAddress;
    address private CommissionContractAddress;
    address private MasterWhitelistingContract;
    bool private isGoldenBadgeUser;
    address private NftMintingDeploymentContract;
    address private NftTraderDeploymentContract;
    address public nftMintingContract;

    event collectionCreated(address owner, address deployedAt);

    constructor(
        address _ARolesContractAddress, 
        address _commissionContractAddress, 
        address _masterWLContractAddress,
        address _nftMintingDeploymentContract,
        address _nftTraderDeploymentContract 
    ) {
        ARolesContractAddress = _ARolesContractAddress;
        CommissionContractAddress = _commissionContractAddress;
        MasterWhitelistingContract = _masterWLContractAddress;
        NftMintingDeploymentContract = _nftMintingDeploymentContract;
        NftTraderDeploymentContract = _nftTraderDeploymentContract;
    }

    // Checking is a user, golden badge user.
    modifier checkUser() {
        (isGoldenBadgeUser) = IMasterWhiteListing(MasterWhitelistingContract).isGoldenBadgeUser(
            msg.sender
        );
        _;
    }
    
    // Getting collection creation fee based on condition(Normal_user & GBUser).
    modifier getCollectionCreationFee() {
        string memory user = isGoldenBadgeUser? "GetFeeAndCommission_GB()": "GetFeeAndCommission_NU()";
        (, bytes memory _data) = CommissionContractAddress.call(
                abi.encodeWithSignature(user)
        );
        (collectionCreationFee, , , ,collectionCreationCommission) = abi.decode(_data, (uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256));
        _;
    }    
   
    function createCollection(string memory NAME, string memory SYMBOL)
        public
        payable
        checkUser
        getCollectionCreationFee
    {   
        // Checking user whitelisted or not
        (_whitelisted) = IMasterWhiteListing(MasterWhitelistingContract).checkWhitelisted(
            msg.sender
        );

        if (_whitelisted) {    
            if (msg.value != collectionCreationFee) {
                revert Insufficient_CollectionFee_sent();
            }

            (PSuperAdmin, MPSuperAdmin) = IAdminRoles(ARolesContractAddress).admin_Addresses();

            uint256 p_commission = collectionCreationFee / 100 * collectionCreationCommission;
            payable(MPSuperAdmin).transfer(collectionCreationFee - p_commission);
            payable(PSuperAdmin).transfer(p_commission);

            nftMintingContract = IDeployNftMinting(NftMintingDeploymentContract).deployNftMintingContract(
                NAME, 
                SYMBOL,  
                isGoldenBadgeUser,
                MPSuperAdmin,
                PSuperAdmin,
                CommissionContractAddress, 
                MasterWhitelistingContract,
                NftTraderDeploymentContract
            );
            s_userCollecions[msg.sender].push(nftMintingContract);
            s_allCollections.push(nftMintingContract);
            emit collectionCreated(msg.sender, nftMintingContract);
        } else {
            revert User_not_whitelisted();
        }
    }

    function getNftMintingContractAddress() public view returns(address) {
        return address(nftMintingContract);
    }

}
```

When I call `createCollection` function, event `collectionCreated` is emitted even when the transaction is successful.

Comment: Hey!, would be possible to elaborate a bit more, on what is exactly the problem and when is happening?

Comment: event is emmiting on successful collection creation? According to your description.

Comment: Please give the example output of the log you are reading to assess wether or not there are events emitted

Comment: I need to get the msg.sender and nftMinting contract Address in the event, but it doesn't emit the event collectionCreated! even though I successfully created a collection(I tested it by printing the nftMinting contract!)

Comment: @AMaajith If the transaction that executes `createCollection` has been successful then it should have generated the events. If no events were generated then it has reverted. Check the transaction status, make sure you have provided enough gas, and the parameters do not revert.